# How to detect black color percentage from the image in every rectangle section using opencv2?

Tags: opencv

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74uIJ.png)

(Newbie Post) I am new in opencv and i wanna to ask a question, how can i detect the black color percentage from the image in every rectangle section, my final goal is i want to show their own black color percentage in the rectangle section respectively. As you can see from the image, there are alot of gray dot.

Is countNonZero is a right function ? I saw quite a few post using
(height * weight) - nonzero) / float((height * weight) this formula.

Comment: Your formula looks ok and `countNonZero()` should be fine too. An alternative is to threshold values below 1 to zero (black) and values of 1 or more to 255 (white) to visualise the absolutely black pixels. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Mark, i will give it a try